# How to configure JsonResult serializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I'm having an issue when returning some data from a controller to the view, a very basic Dictionary<string, string>, and I can't find the exact cause. Here's the action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
           {
                var userExists = db.UserAuth.Where(ua => ua.Email == model.Email).Count() > 0;
                if (userExists)
                {
                    var uAuth = db.UserAuth.Where(ua => ua.Email == model.Email).ToList();
                    if (uAuth[0].Senha == model.Senha)
                    {
                        if (Request.Cookies.Get("CookieLogged") == null)
                        {
                            var CookieLogged = new HttpCookie("CookieLogged");
                            CookieLogged.Value = "true";
                            CookieLogged.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4);
                            CookieLogged.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                            Response.Cookies.Add(CookieLogged);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var Logged = Request.Cookies.Get("CookieLogged");
                            Logged.Value = "true";
                            Logged.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4);
                            Response.Cookies.Set(Logged);
                        }

                        var JsonRedirect = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        JsonRedirect.Add("redirect", Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
                        return Json(JsonRedirect);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var JsonWarning = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        JsonWarning.Add("warning", "Senha não confere");
                        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonWarning);
                        return Content(jsonString, "application/json");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var JsonWarning = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    JsonWarning.Add("warning", "Email não confere ou usuário não existe");
                    return Json(JsonWarning, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var JsonError = new Dictionary<string, Exception>();
                JsonError.Add("errorEx", ex);
                return Json(JsonError, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> JsonWarning = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            JsonWarning.Add("warning", "Dados inválidos");
            return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonWarning), "application/json");
        }

        
    }
```

It works perfectly fine in local but breaks once I publish it to the hosting site. The request returns with 500 and the error message says `System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.` , and the stack trace suggests me the problem might be in the way the dictionary is being serialized, but that's just a guess. Stack trace from the error:

> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1446
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +480
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1324
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +127
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1279
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +480
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1324
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +480
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1324
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +480
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1324
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +480
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1324
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +480
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1324
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeDictionary(IDictionary o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +505
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1218
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +29
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +64
> System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +347
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +198 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +577
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

So, is there a way to prevent the serializer from entering this loop? I also tried serializing before and sending to the view with `return Content()` but the result is the same. And my research on the topic showed this issue with EF classes and DataTables, so I really don't understand why my simple dictionary is not passing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) What version of [tag:asp.net-mvc] are you using?  `JavaScriptSerializer` is quite old.  2) Which code path in the above code are you going through?  There are several `if` statements so it's not clear exactly what is happening.  Could you [edit] the code down into a [mcve]?

Comment: You know, you might get the traceback you are seeing if you are trying to serialize an `Exception`, since `Exception` internally contains a dictionary.  And in fact, you do return a `Dictionary<string, Exception>();` along one code path.  Could this be the path that is causing the problem?  Why are you returning a dictionary of exceptions?

Comment: 1) The Assembly for `System.Web.Mvc` is in the 5.2.7.0 version. 2) All paths in general get me this problem, but it didn't crash during the background process to generate an exception. Right now it is crashing when everything is fine and the controller returns the redirect url, and when the password does not match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why are you using a Dictionary, but you can try this:

```
return Json(new { redirect = Url.Action("Index", "Home") });
```

Comment: I'm using dictionaries to work with some JS/jQuery in the page. It is very basic info to make sure the user knows what is happening, so I didn't think it was worth of having a class just so I can parse it. And I tried that shorter version too but it gave me the same error. I'm guessing it has to do with the way `return Json()` tries to serialize. Then again, it works just fine in the local machine...